# Prevent newline at top of column in Apple Pages?

Tags: iwork-pages

I've setup two columns in Apple Pages version 5.1. I'd prefer that a newline not appear at the top of a column, as it is not necessary. Suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I changed my styles so that there is spacing after each paragraph. Then I removed the extra (double) line breaks.